# Java GUI based on Fields in class

Tags: java, user-interface

I need to generate GUI in Java at runtime based on class fields.

I'm working on web service so I need to dynamically generate GUI at client side. For example, if I have a class on my web service that has the fields `String name`, `int number` and `ArrayList<> list`, I need to generate a GUI that will have 2 `JTextField`s and one `JList`.

Is there any API or something else that can help me to do this?

Comment: have you looked at java reflections? annotations would also be a fun way to do it

Comment: I didn't see that i can make that with reflection API. I tried to code my self class for that but i cant really code for all java types

Comment: break down the problem first.  get the dynamic GUI creation first, then look into building the GUI from the class you need to work with

Comment: Well the dynamic GUI creation is the problem i can get fields from class that i need but i dont know how to map that fields into proper Swing components and i cant find anything on web to help me

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a "naked objects"-like approach.

While this approach is very good at getting some sort of initial GUI, the manner in which the GUI is generated tends to make even the most trivial GUI changes require changes to your object driving the GUI generation.

This tends to run counter to many approaches designed to minimize the need to rewrite your core logic when you need a new GUI feature.

Now that you've been warned, if you still want to step on this landmine, I'll show you the way, in pseduocode

```
 public Component generateComponent(Object object) {
   Class c = object.getClass();
   Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
   for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      if (m.getName().startsWith("get")) {
        Class returnClass = m.getReturnClass();
        if (returnClass.equals(String.class)) {
           add(new TextBox(...);
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Quickly you'll have to make decisions about what methods to include / exclude, and the mechanisms you use to make that decision.  Then you have to make decisions about how to present the information, and you have to make the new JComponents list to changes to call back the relevant "set..." methods.

In short, it sounds like a great idea, until you do it.  Then it becomes one of those issues where you got what you asked for instead of what you wanted.

Comment: If you do go with the approach, I highly recommend you use a "naked objects" toolkit, instead of rolling your own.  The only exception to this guideline would be if you were curious as to how such things work, and the experience of rolling your own was what you really wanted (as opposed to working software).

Comment: I already tried this way but the problem is i would have to do tone of if statments to check every posible Class so i would have if returnClass.equals(String.class) then add TextBox, if returnClass.equals(Boolean.class) then add checkBox and so on i need some sort of API or some library to help me map these types into corresponding Swing components i hope you understend me. Sorry i never heard of naked objects i will google that

Comment: The reason it gets hard is because it's much easier to write software for what you need than it is to write software than can handle any unforeseen need at run time.  Even the naked objects approach eventually has to make some trade-offs, like using a limited number of type-to-string and string-to-type adapters.

Comment: I m reading about it on wiki it seams like it can help me with my problem

Comment: It seems that way; however, I'm going to warn you that it's about as good a path to a decent solution as travelling to New York via the Moon.  There's a reason it's not taken the industry by storm despite being available for nearly ten years now.  I'm almost of the opinion that it's an Anti-Pattern.

Comment: So what do you have other suggestion form me to look for ?

Comment: Write the GUI you want, and do the data binding in a MVC like manner.  Much cleaner, and you can have one data element drive multiple presentations, and multiple data elements drive one presentation.

Comment: I cant write GUI coz i never know what elements i will have, i must generate GUI at runtime and components in Frame of gui must match fields in my class

Comment: If you don't know how to write a GUI, you don't know how to write software to write a GUI automatically.  I'd suggest reading a book, like O'Reilly's Swing Programming book.  It is big, but it does a good job of covering the fundamentals and the details.  What you are suggesting is actually _more_ difficult than writing a GUI, you are suggesting writing a program that _writes_ GUIs for every possible combination of GUI components.

Comment: I know how to write a GUI but it would be nearly imposible to write one myself that's why i need some kind of help for generating gui based on class fields.

Comment: You've been given the tools, and the advice.  Now it is time to make of it what you will.  Eventually you will learn to write a GUI either way, either in writing the GUI, or in debugging the output of your "dynamic GUI builder".